# Last basic block of a function in LLVM

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

Does the back() of a Function guarantee to return the terminator basic block of CFG in LLVM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think, since there's no such a thing as a "terminator BB": there very well may be multiple BBs terminated by a return.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a function with more than one terminator BBs? Even if there are multiple returns, there should be a BB with a phi to "collect" all the return BBs, right?

Comment: Nope, in fact there's even a pass called UnifyFunctionExitNodes that does exactly what its name says, i.e. getting rid of multiple exits from a function

Answer (score 1):

No. There could be multiple terminator basic blocks of a function, for instance a function containing multiple return statements. each basic block that contains a return statement from the function will then be called a terminator block or terminator basic block. To detect all basic blocks that are terminator basic blocks (i.e. contain a return statement) do the following:

```
runOnFunction {
   for BB in F:
      for I in BB:
          if (ReturnInst *RI = dyn_cast<ReturnInst> I)
             BB is terminator Basic Block
          endif
      endfor
   endfor
}
```